# Who Am I Puzzle

Tags: word, knowledge, visual

The grid you see below is composed of unit squares. Can you figure out who I am?

---

```
                                           l=1/2
                                           r=1/4
                                           w=1/4
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> Samuel Morse - the inventor of Morse code.

> The squares contains one of two equations:
>      l*w - which defines the area of a rectangle.
>      pi*r^2 - which defines the area of a circle.
>
>  If we take the rectangle as a dash, and the circle as a dot, we have the following pattern:
>  - -
>  - - -
>  . - .
>  . .
>  .
>
>  Which is Morse code for "Morse"